# Unable to lanuch android application in emulator using appium

Tags: java, automation, appium

I am using 
**Selenium java jar** version: 3.4.0
**appium** for desktop version: 1.4.13.1
**java client** version: 5.0.0-BETA9

code and desired capabilities are:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
        File apk = new File("src");
        File fs = new File(apk,"betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk");


        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Test");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "50");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath() );
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver= new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap); 
        driver.quit();
    }
```

}

but when i run it i got following **errors in eclipse console**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LMKT-LT-81', ip: '10.11.11.57', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:161)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:76)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:111)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:112)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:73)
at base.main(base.java:21)
```

and following error on appium:

```
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Users\\sisatti\\workspace\\Sel3.4\\src\\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Test","newCommandTimeout":"50"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Users\\sisatti\\workspace\\Sel3.4\\src\\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Test","newCommandTimeout":"50"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)
> info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session b22f01e6-aa1f-40df-b4bf-242f7be87eaf
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_131
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk
> info: [debug] badging package: com.lmkt.wfmdemo
> info: [debug] badging act: com.lmkt.wfmdemo.activities.LaunchScreenActivity
> info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.lmkt.wfmdemo/com.lmkt.wfmdemo.activities.LaunchScreenActivity
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 24
> info: Device API level is: 24
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
> info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
> info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk" "C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Temp\com.lmkt.wfmdemo" 
> info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
> info: [debug] Setting language to default
 info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Users\\sisatti    \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.lmkt.wfmdemo\\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk AndroidManifest.xml
> info: [debug] Set app process to: com.lmkt.wfmdemo
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
> info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk
> info: [debug] App already signed.
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk
> info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
> info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\zipalign.exe
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\sisatti\workspace\Sel3.4\src\betaWFM-v19_15thJune2017.apk C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Temp\11772-4612-746m00\appium.tmp
> info: [debug] MD5 for app is a4d18a355b0b6ad0eaa66b444e8f557c
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/a4d18a355b0b6ad0eaa66b444e8f557c.apk"
> info: [debug] Getting install status for com.lmkt.wfmdemo
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 24
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.lmkt.wfmdemo"
> info: [debug] App is installed
> info: App is already installed, resetting app
> info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.lmkt.wfmdemo"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm clear com.lmkt.wfmdemo"
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
> info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\sisatti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
> 
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> info: [debug] Error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
> 
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
>     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":    {"message":"A new session could not be created.     (Original error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\\Program Files     (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\settings_apk\\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: Failed to install C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\settings_apk\\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11271.814 ms - 654
```

tried to solve by changing different version but unable to solve it.
appium is showing error but at same time emulator is showing that application as installed.
any one having same issue? Please suggest solution

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure path to apk file is correctly configured in appium as shown in the image: 
   [Android settings for app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3FIY.png)
2. Make sure appium is running by clicking play button: [image]
3. Make sure path to apk is correctly configured in the code.
4. Some desired capabilities configurations:

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
           capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
           capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
           capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
           capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot","true");
           capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
           File app= new File("app-qa-release.apk");
           capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
           driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

Comment: apk is correctly configured in appium and code.
Please have look into code and suggest changes accordingly, if any.

Comment: is appium running while you run your script?

Comment: yes, appium is in running state. thats why i am getting logs.

Comment: try using AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
if not please provide line number with the help of eclipse at which the exception occurs

Comment: Mohsin issue is still there, can you please contact me on skype (shahzeb.satti).